# Cubot X9 does not turn on after update, also not recognised by computer (unknown device in Device Manager)

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, connection-issues, rom, usb-connection-mode

I have Cubot X9, ordered from China. after the update it gave me an error.
The phone restarts, but I cannot enter recovery mode. I tried to flash new ROM, but it gave an error.

Now nothing works, and I cannot enter recovery mode.

The PC does not recognize the phone because it is off, I installed the drivers but to no effect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try but has no effect; x
There is no VID and PID code, how to find the right driver?